# I don't understand this code.I want to split him up

Tags: python

I don't quite understand how this paragraph is written.
The source code is as follows.

```
line = [cell.value for cell in col if cell.value != None]
```

I want to understand how to write this code.
I tried to use loops, but the results were different.

```
for cell in col:
   if cell.value != None:
       line = cell.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. FYI, the one-line syntax is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Here is the equivalent.

```
line = list()
for cell in col:
   if cell.value != None:
       line.append(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're keep overriding the `line` variable while it should be a list:

```
line = []
for cell in col:
   if cell.value != None:
       line.append(cell.value)
```

As you see, the one-liner has two square brackets around it, so it becomes a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in right direction but here line will be an array and each value is appended in the array

so code will look like following

```py
line = []
for cell in col:
   if cell.value != None:
       line.append(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = [cell.value for cell in col if cell.value != None]
print(line)

line = []
for cell in col:
   if cell.value != None:
       line.append(cell.value)
print(line)

line = list()
for cell in col:
   if cell.value != None:
       line.append(cell.value)
print(line)
```

## Translate to an empty list and write the contents as you did and add them to your list by append. I put here print line from me, you can ignore it.